# Start Firefox ThreadLocal Driver In Selenium 3 - Java

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-grid

I just updated to Selenium 3.0.0-beta3 and am trying to execute tests in Firefox 45.

I have downloaded v.10 of the geckodriver.exe and added that to my PATH environment variables. I am also setting the system property in the code for the geckodriver like I do when I use the Chrome driver, which works perfectly fine, however, I still end up with the following TestNG message:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver
>   executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;
>   for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The
>   latest version can be downloaded from
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases Command duration or
>   timeout: 411 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision:
>   '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time: '2016-02-11
>   11:22:43' System info: host: 'VMP-2316', ip: '10.80.50.100', os.name:
>   'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_92' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

Here is the code I am using to set the driver:

```
// Set Driver
threadDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/geckodriver.exe");

dc.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.firefox().getBrowserName());
dc.setCapability("marionette", true);

threadDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), dc));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way would be to define the path of the driver in the command line launching the server/node:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=path/to/geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are running your tests against a Grid.
When the tests are run against a Grid, there are three machines involved.

1. Machine_A - This is where the test cases will be spun off for execution
2. Machine_B - This is where the Grid Hub will be running.
3. Machine_C - This is where the Grid node will be running and the machine where the browsers are going to be open.

In your case you would need to ensure that Machine_C has either

1. The geckodriver binary available in the PATH variable (or)
2. The geckodriver binary path is informed to selenium node via the JVM argument `-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver` (As Florent mentioned)

The statement `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/geckodriver.exe");` will have its effect on Machine_A and not on Machine_C (where it really should be acting upon).

Hope that helps!